# Writing same Spark Streaming Output to different destinations

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a DStream and I want to write each element to a socket and to cassandra DB.

I found a solution that use Apache Kafka and two consumer, one write to database and other write to socket.

Is there a way to do that without using this workaround?

I use Java so please post code on this language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to apply two different actions to the rdd within the `DStream`: One to save to cassandra and one to send the data to whatever other output.
Also, cache the rdd before these actions to improve performance.

(in pseudo code as I don't do Java)

```
dstream.foreachRDD{rdd =>
    rdd.cache()
    rdd.saveToCassandra(...)
    rdd.foreach(...) // or rdd.foreachPartition(...)
}
```

Comment: are `rdd.saveToCassandra(...)` and `rdd.foreach(...)` executing in parallel or sequentially?

Comment: @theShadow89 they will be scheduled one after the other (sequentially)